# REST service in Symfony2, with a dot in a parameter (FOSRestBundle)

Tags: php, rest, symfony, format, fosrestbundle

I have a REST API done in `Symfony2` with `FOSRestBundle`
Globally, it works but..
I have a route like this

```
/api/mymethod/{param}
```

with the implicit `.{_format}`
When my param has no dot inside,

```
.../mymethod/toto.json
```

it works.
But if it has a dot, I'm getting the message

> ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /api/mymethod/toto.com.json"" at C:\outils\wamp64\www\spapiDev\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 2100

Where am I wrong? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid using dots in your route parameters. Try to use a slug instead.

But, to achieve what you want, you can add a regex to your `param` like this:

```
# ..
requirements:
    param: .+
```

You can check [this cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html) for more details.